# How to copy usb stick with multiple partitions?

Tags: partitioning, usb, scripts, clipboard

I have a usb stick with two partitions FAT 32 adn ext3. First one is used to boot from using SystemRescueCD. Second one contains the image I use with image recovery tool.
I have to copy such an usb 10 times so I thouhgt maybe there is an easy way to do this, 
something like `cp /dev/sdb` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can clone it with dd.

assuming your flash drive is /dev/sbd and you are cloning it to a second flash drive, /dev/sdc

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror
```

You can save a compressed image to your harddrive

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb ibs=4096 conv=noerror | gzip > your_image.gz
```

Then use the image to make a new flash

```
dd if=your_image.gz | gunzip | dd of=/dev/sdc
```

Comment: You are most welcome

Comment: For big partitions (> 500GB, say), it's very worth [optimizing the block size parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27772496/64911).

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `dd` utility.

Basically, `dd if=/dev/xda of=/dev/xdb` where `xda` is the input drive ('`if` means input file, `of` means output file).

See this post:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=5627660#post5627660

`dd` is a utility for bit for bit copies. Make sure to try this on something you don't care about before doing it to a mission critical usb stick.